# Do Raritanium and Holocard upgrades on weapons only count towards enemies killed with that weapon?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-2016

Some weapons like the Photon Drum have in their raritanium upgrade path, "Increase Holocard drop rate by 4%." Is this upgrade only for enemies killed with the Photon Drum or is it across all weapons?

Answer (score 3):

It's exclusively for that weapon. They don't increase the drop rate of when you are killing them with just your Omniwrench, for one.

On the flip side, the bonuses for completing certain card sets apply to all weapons, Omniwrench included.

I use the Omniwrench as an example as it can't be upgraded with Raritanium, and so has no bonuses on its own.